# Use AppSync and Amazon RDS with serverless-graphql

Tags: node.js, graphql, amazon-rds, serverless-framework, aws-appsync

There is [this great repository](https://github.com/serverless/serverless-graphql) with example implementations of different serverless scenarios.

Right now I'm struggling with the combination of AppSync and Amazon RDS. I tried the implementation of the standalone rds, and the appsync examples provided in the repository. These are working like a charm.
But obviously there are many differences and difficulties if you'd like to combine these technologies. I used the schema, resolver and handler functions from the rds directory and combined it with the appsync lambda implementation. I adjusted the mapping templates and updated the serverless.yml file.

I could successfully deploy the whole appsync service and all resources without any errors. I'm able to access the graphql endpoint from graphiql and do my queries. But when I try it from the appsync console I get null as a response. I guess it has something to do with the mapping templates, but I'm not quite sure.

Has anybody got any suggestions or maybe a working example of this specific combination?

Comment: hey!, how did you combined app sync with rds+lambda could you help me out in how to get data in realtime. Thanks

Comment: @SahajRana I'll create a sample git repository of my implementation in a few days

Comment: that would be great! and I have actually successfully added appSync+awsLambda+RDS with Android app with real-time integration. So if you need any help, please let me know!

Comment: @SahajRana Feel free to check out my sample implementation in my answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I finally could figure out a working implementation for this specific setup which I want to share with all of you.
Check out my [serverless-graphql-appsync-rds](https://github.com/getsbydev/serverless-graphql-appsync-rds) repository on GitHub and leave me some feedback!
Note that this repository contains just the source code without any explanations. I'll create a better documentation in the near future.