# Unable to serialise AWSDate from RDS in AppSync response mapping template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

I'm building an AppSync project using serverless Aurora as my db, and stumbled across this strange error:

```
"Can't serialize value (/getUsers/created_at) : Unable to serialize `2019-09-28 07:36:13` as a valid DateTime Object."
```

This happens when I get a User object which looks like this:

```
type Users {
  id: String!
  name: String!
  description: String
  created_at: AWSDateTime
  updated_at: AWSDateTime
  logged_in: AWSDateTime
}
```

The error seems to be happening because `$utils.rds.toJsonObject($ctx.result)[0][0]` can't parse an AWSDateTime. Which makes anything with a date impossible to serve from the database.

If I simply select the object without dates `["SELECT id,name,description FROM Users WHERE id='$ctx.args.id'"]` it works fine.

So how should dates be handled in AWS AppSync and Aurora? I have been unable to find any example or reference to handling dates in the documentation. :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I accidentally found the answer in a repo connected to this question [Use AppSync and Amazon RDS with serverless-graphql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50069352/use-appsync-and-amazon-rds-with-serverless-graphql)

It turns out, like user [dev1702](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5448519/dev1702) discovered, that `$utils.rds.toJsonObject($ctx.result)[0][0]` cannot parse a RDS Timestampt INTO an GraphQl AWSDate format.

So simply changing the graphql schema type from:

`created_at: AWSDateTime`

to:

`created_at: String`

solves this issue.

**A Note:** If you are facing this error after changing your scheme column type to `AWSDateTime`, just visit the DynamoDB console and update records that do not in the format of `ISO 8601`.

Comment: You have to convert it manually using AWSTimestamp and "SELECT cast(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(lastHeartbeat) as unsigned) as lastHeartbeat FROM User "

Answer (score 3):

You can `SELECT to_char(created_at, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"') FROM Users` which will work for `AWSDateTime`.

Another one is `SELECT created_at::date FROM Users` which will work for `AWSDate`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to enter your date time as => 2022-08-01T10:10:42-05:00

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output from SQL in a format that `AWSDateTime` supports **and want to support milliseconds** you can do:

```
SELECT to_char(created_at, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.MS"Z"') FROM Users
```